# Github: how to revoke permission given to a site?

Tags: github

Some time ago I logged in at some website using my github account. I gave it a permission to access to private repositories.

How can I revoke this permission now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can revoke authorizations here:
https://github.com/settings/integrations/authorizations
and here:
https://github.com/settings/applications